# Passing textbox text as a stored procedure parameter for output in a gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, textbox, parameter-passing

I have two textboxes and two gridviews.

The textboxes are populated with coordinates from javascript variables which change according to which cell is clicked on in the first gridview. This works ok:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbGrade" runat="server" CssClass="hideOnprint" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbKS2" runat="server" CssClass="hideOnprint" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

I would like to pass the two text values to a stored procedure once the textboxes are populated by the gridview cell click ie once they change.

This stored procedure will then output results to the second gridview.  The stored procedure works correctly when I test it with dummy values, but the two textbox parameters won't populate from the textboxes and therefore the second gridview is not displaying.

So the input is working ok and the output is working ok, but connecting the two together is eluding me.

Here is the asp for the gridview and parameters. The dropdown text parameters work ok:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvProgressCohorts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsProgressCohorts">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Column1" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsProgressCohorts" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MaltingsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="spProgressCohorts" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DdlYear" Name="StuYear" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDataCollection" Name="DataCollection" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DdlSubject" Name="SubjectName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DdlTeachingGroup" Name="TeachingGroup" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSubgroup" Name="Subgroup" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbGrade" DefaultValue="" Name="Result" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbKS2" DefaultValue="" Name="KS2" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**EDIT:**

As it stands the second gridview is updating correctly, but only when I make a selection from one of my dropdown controls. What I need to happen is when the values in the textboxes are updated the second grid refreshes based on the selection made on the page.

**EDIT:**

I've added a textchange event to one of my textboxes which updates the second gridview when I manually change the value in the textbox and then focus away from the textbox. I just need to know how to achieve this when the value in the textbox changes automatically when clicking the first gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to the javascript used to populate the textboxes when the initial gridview is clicked. This triggers the textbox text changed ie when the textbox is populated automatically the text focus is trigger server side without manual intervention as if the text had been selected and text entered and the textbox had then lost focus:

```
__doPostBack(document.getElementById("<%=tbKS2.ClientID%>").name, '')
```